# Is fiber to computer(without the use of LAN cables in between) possible?? Are any further developments getting carried out towards this goal?

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-hardware, electronics, fiber-optics, networking

All of us know well that the **fiber to home(FTTH)** connections are a trend nowadays. Every nation is planning to replace the existing metal wires with optical fiber cables. But we also see that the fiber is only used till the networking device and not the client nodes like PC or laptop. LAN cables made up of copper wires are used for this purpose. So, is there any possibility to directly link our devices through optical fiber cables with networking devices replacing the metal LAN cables and is there any ongoing effort being carried out to eliminate this need of LAN cables and insert optical fiber cables directly into the client machines like our home PCs or laptops?

Comment: I assume that there will be some practical difficulty as the fibre is quite delicate and should not be bent too much. By having a copper link to the PC, the part which the user often handles will be robust. Take a look at this also (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK)

Comment: There has to be a transistion from fiber to: TV, LAN (wired), WiFi (wireless).  If the only thing you were connecting to was a computer, the need would be there, but much of fibre is providing entertainment, so the transition has to be made.

Comment: It's a thing, kindof -- there's this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_transistor   ... there are also some crazy [100 gigabit optoelectronics](https://www.macom.com/Optoelectronics), which could make it possible to interface a high speed conventional IC directly to an optical bus, which sounds like what the question is describing? Cutting edge stuff, way over my head